# use an inbound VM or JMS endpoint with transactional delivery to perform retries on the outbound FTP endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

Alternatively, you could remove until-successful and use an inbound VM or JMS endpoint with transactional delivery to perform retries on the outbound FTP endpoint.

could you please provide me the example on this with VM?

this related to below question

- [how to make until successful as synchronous to retry mechanism for FTP Outbound in mule 3.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661113/how-to-make-until-successful-as-synchronous-to-retry-mechanism-for-ftp-outbound)

Answer (score 0):

How about try something like the below

```
<flow name="transactionalVM">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="orders" exchange-pattern="one-way">
        <vm:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
     </vm:inbound-endpoint>
     <file:outbound-endpoint ref="receivedOrders"/> <!-- replace this with your FTP endpoint -->
</flow>
```

Look at [transaction management](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Transaction+Management) in Mule to figure out how the retries can be controlled, right now its going to try endlessly

Now if you are wondering how the file outbound is part of the transaction have a look at [this](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Transaction+Management) (Configuration Tips and Tricks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206626/how-does-a-non-transactional-outbound-work-with-a-transactional-inbound-in-mule), hint [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/lrco-overview.html)

Comment: will it work in 3.4.2. I more thing shall I need to use FTP connector reference with reconnection parameter?

Comment: Good question my understanding is that reconnection parameter applies only to inbound endpoints. Yes I think it should work with 3.4.2 also (i have not tested it, but have no reason to believe the contrary). I related more elaborate and possibly confusing discussion [here](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/does_reconnect_work_for_outbound_ftp_endpoints)

Comment: I am asking for outbound FTP .could you please confirm me wheather it wil work for or not?

Comment: Do post follow up questions, in case you have problems during the implementation

Comment: reconnection parameters are not working with outbound FTP which has given as connector refernce properties. It is not retrying.. could you please provide the solution

Comment: Why are you using in re-connection parameters ? Update your question with what you exactly do to reproduce your problem. [re-connection is not the same as retrying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746247/which-mule-transports-does-the-re-connection-strategy-work-with)